# Android App using Volley get race condition

Tags: android, api, asynchronous, callback, android-volley

I'm developing an Android Mobile Application and one of the most important functionality of the app itself is being able to talk with a third-party API Service.

The third party service, offering these API, wants a "beacon" to be included into every API request i made.

The "beacon" is a "long integer" and it must be unique and incremental for every request.

The problem is: 
I'm firing a couple of these request and i do not know which of these requests will complete first so i'm running into a race condition: where the second request ends quickly before the first request invalidating the first request!

When a button is clicked the following action will be executed:

```
public void fireRequests(View view)
{
    long first_beacon = System.nanoTime();
    fireFirstRequest(view, first_beacon);

    long second_beacon = System.nanoTime();
    fireSecondRequest(view, second_beacon);
}
```

I'm using Volley in a proper way, setting up callback etc.. example here:

fireFirstRequest method:

```
public void fireFirstRequest(View view, long beacon)
{
    final ThirdPartyLib api_lib = new ThirdPartyLib(getActivity());

    api_lib.doOperationA(beacon, new ThirdPartyLib.MyOwnCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void update(JSONObject jsonObject)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject result = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                /* my code */
                Log.d("doOperationA", result)
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

fireSecondRequest method:

```
public void fireSecondRequest(View view, long beacon)
{
    final ThirdPartyLib api_lib = new ThirdPartyLib(getActivity());

    api_lib.doOperationB(beacon, new ThirdPartyLib.MyOwnCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void update(JSONObject jsonObject)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject result = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                /* my code */
                Log.d("doOperationB", result)
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the execution log:

```
03-12 14:26:56.252  18769-18769/it.example.app D/Volley: queued doOperationA
03-12 14:26:58.124  18769-18769/it.example.app D/Volley: queued doOperationB
03-12 14:26:59.433  18769-18769/it.example.app D/App: doOperationB: {
    "error": false,
    "payload": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
03-12 14:27:04.181  18769-18769/it.example.app D/App: doOperationA: {
    "error": true,
    "errorMessage": "invalid beacon"
    "payload": {}
}
```

The question is: what's the best way to keep track of beacon before firing an API request or to maintain a "execution order" separation even if we are talking of ASync request?

My rough solution is to call the fireSecondRequest() inside the callback of the fireFirstRequest() when i'm completely sure that first request is done.
I know, this is the best way to kill the awesome world of async requests.

modified action:

```
public void fireRequests(View view)
{
    long first_beacon = System.nanoTime();
    fireFirstRequest(view, first_beacon);
}
```

fireFirstRequest modified method with **final** View parameter:

```
public void fireFirstRequest(final View view, long beacon)
{
    final ThirdPartyLib api_lib = new ThirdPartyLib(getActivity());

    api_lib.doOperationA(beacon, new ThirdPartyLib.MyOwnCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void update(JSONObject jsonObject)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject result = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                /* my code */
                Log.d("doOperationA", result)

                /* fire second request */
                // EDIT
                fireSecondRequest(view, System.nanoTime());
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add the part of your code which initiates the Volley `RequestQueue`, but I'm assuming you're creating the default way using:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, stack);
```

When you do this, you get a request queue which allows for 4 concurrent requests by default. You can see this by looking at the constructor this method uses to create a request queue:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 4;

...

public RequestQueue(Cache cache, Network network) {
    this(cache, network, DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
}
```

You can overcome this issue if instead of using the default method for creating a `RequestQueue`, you create your own `RequestQueue` with a thread pool size of 1. This way, there can be no 2 concurrent requests, and requests will be sent in the order they are dispatched.

The downside with this, of course, is that this can dramatically slow down your app. If all requests must wait until the previous request is finished, this creates a serious bottleneck in your app.

Perhaps consider using more than 1 request queue, and only use this special request queue for requests that rely on this special constraint.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think of my own solution? Calling the second request when the first one is completed?

Comment: it's fair, but seems a bit cumbersome, and will lead you into whats referred to as "callback hell" where half your code is nested in callbacks. With this method, any request which relies on this beacon can simply use a different request queue than the rest of your app's requests, and you can simply forget that this problem exists.

Comment: by your answer i assume that using different request queue means that request queued into the second queue will not get processed until all request queued into the first queue are completed. it this right? by your point of view what is a completed request? a request with its own response or a request simply launched? sorry for these dumb questions

Comment: A request is considered completed when the thread responsible for processing it has finished. This includes the actual request, and any pre/post processing of the request which isnt delegated to a different (usually main) thread.